# Send array from php to js with ajax and json

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, mysqli

I am trying to send an array from php (that I have taken from a mysql table to js). Although there a lot of examples out there I can't seem to make any of them work. The code that I have reached so far is:

*php_side.php*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
//$q = intval($_GET['q']);
header("Content-type: text/javascript");

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","Tileiatriki"); 
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

//mysqli_select_db($con,"users_in_calls");
$sql="SELECT * FROM users_in_calls";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);


/*while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
     echo $row['User1_number'];
     echo "<br/>";
     echo $row['User2_number'];
         echo "<br/>";
     echo $row['canvas_channel'];
         echo "<br/>";
}*/
echo json_encode($result);

    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

*test_ajax.html*

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $.getJSON('php_side.php', function(data) {
        $(data).each(function(key, value) {
            // Will alert 1, 2 and 3
            alert(value);
        });
     });
   });
```

This is my first app that I use something like this, so please be a little patient.

Comment: You are also sending all html from the page, in other words your json response will be mixed with all html markup of the page. Move your php code at the top and terminate with a `exit;` after you have called `mysqli_close()`. Of course then you won't be able to actually view the markup in the page. Also `header()` can not be called after any output has been done. Enable error_reporting and you will see what is going on.

Comment: @Cyclone i did not understand your comment. What i am doing is i read the array from the mysql (hopefully correct) and then i try to pass it to `test_ajax.html`. Where is the wrong to that??

Comment: It shouldn't be to hard to understand, the ajax request gets ***ALL*** the content from the file it gets, not just the JSON, but all the HTML as well, and that's not valid JSON at all, it's mangled up stuff, or in other words the **entire** content of the output from `php_side.php` file, the same thing you'd see if you'd opened that file in the browser. `$.getJSON` expects to get **just** valid JSON.

Comment: @Cyclone Is it possible to write the above in a workable manner, so it is more easily understandable in what i am wrong?

Comment: @adeneo Wait a sec. What i have understood till now (thought at least) is that what is returned to ajax is what is inside the `echo`.Is that correct?

Comment: php will return all literal strings in your script and the result of echo. also you don't wanna be echoing the result_object. call $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC) and json_encode that instead.

Comment: @KeithA yeah i just found out about that now thanks :)

Comment: since you're returning a json object, a proper header would be: header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

Comment: @KeithA what difference does it make? If i do not put it won't work properly?

Comment: not only is it good semantic coding, it also tells whoever requested your data, exactly what it is and will therefore parse it correctly. in your case, getJson might be smart enough to know what it is even without a header, but you can't rely on that, it's a good habit to always ensure you have proper headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you're sending the complete page markup mixed with your json response, which of course will not work.

For example imagine that you have the following php script which suppose to return a json response:

```
<div><?php print json_encode(array('domain' => 'example.com')); ?></div>
```

The response from this page would not be json since it also will return the wrapping div element.

You can move your php code to the top of the page or simply remove all the html:

```
<?php
 // uncomment the following two lines to get see any errors
 // ini_set('display_errors', 1);
 // error_reporting(E_ALL);

 // header can not be called after any output has been done
 // notice that you also should use 'application/json' in this case
 header("Content-type: application/json");

 $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","Tileiatriki"); 
 if (!$con) {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
 }

 $sql="SELECT * FROM users_in_calls";
 $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

 // fetch all rows from the result set
 $data = array();
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   $data[] = $row;
 }
 mysqli_close($con);

 echo json_encode($data);

 // terminate the script
 exit;
?>
```